# PHP and MySQL data retrieval issue

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am trying to create a selection list using PHP scripting and variables. I keep getting this error though...

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/12345/public_html/av/tv.php on line 7

my code is posted below. Nt quite sure what I am doing wrong. This is pretty much agoby from the example in PHP & MySWL For Dummiers 4th edition Listing 8-8: Building a Selection List Page 243. Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

```
  <?php
   $user=”12345”;
   $host=”localhost”;
   $password=”12345”;
   $database = “12345”;
   $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
   $query = “SELECT TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY, CO2 FROM ANALOG_SENSORS";
   $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query);
   ?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sensor Type</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action=’processform.php’ method=’POST’>
         <select name=’Sensor Type’>
         <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            extract($row);
            echo “<option value=’$TEMPERATURE’>$TEMPERATURE</option>\n”;
            echo “<option value=’$HUMIDITY’>$HUMIDITY</option>\n”;
            echo “<option value=’$CO2’>$CO2</option>\n”;
            }
            ?>
         </select>
         <input type=’submit’ value=’Select Type of Sensor’ />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do your `"` look like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong quotes in your code either double `“` for `"` and single one `’` which should be `'`, just change them all over your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name=’Sensor Type’>
```

why did you leave space between word in name property ?

Comment: This should be a comment